# Buffer I/O error when writing into the SD card

Tags: partitioning, raspberrypi, sd-card

I tried building a Rpi SD with the NOOBS unzip to the SD, but the Raspberry Pi stopped with I/O error fail on its setup when starting up on the pi.
I tried deleting the partitions which didn't work, and even

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk1 bs=8192
```

which has been working overnight on the 32gb sd and I'm starting to think this won't finish and has some errors on it.

Is there a way I can easily verify this? (F3 command is supposed to do so but it won't run because the SD is plugged in directly to laptop and it thinks it is not-USB-storage).

I see in syslog:

```
Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1, logical block 1645696, lost async page write
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.094955] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 13165576
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.094959] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1, logical block 1645697, lost async page write
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.094974] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 13165584
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.094979] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1, logical block 1645698, lost async page write
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.094992] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 13165592
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.094995] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1, logical block 1645699, lost async page write
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.095002] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 13165600
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.095005] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1, logical block 1645700, lost async page write
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.095012] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 13165608
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.095014] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1, logical block 1645701, lost async page write
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.095021] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 13165616
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.095024] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1, logical block 1645702, lost async page write
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.095031] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 13165624
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.095033] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1, logical block 1645703, lost async page write
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.095040] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 13165632
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.095043] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1, logical block 1645704, lost async page write
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.095050] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk1, sector 13165640
Jun 27 09:15:45 linuxlaptop kernel: [51903.095052] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk1, logical block 1645705, lost async page write
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of the command ```sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb```(if your SD card is ```/dev/sdb``` , otherwise replace that).That might be the bad sector problem with your SD card.

Comment: Also you can use ```sudo e2fsck -cfv /dev/sdb``` to check whether the SD card has bad sectors or not.(It might take quite a while to get done completely , but the first option is much faster because of the self-monitoring infrastructure in the disk)

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I'm thinking it most certainly is but is there any way that can be "marked", fixed?

Comment: Running ```e2fsck -cfpv``` would do that.`-p` would repair the disk.

Comment: Could your block size be too large?  1024 is a common block size.  Maybe you could try a method to write to the SD like Etcher that takes human error out of the equation..  it should NOT take overnight to write an ISO to a SD card.

Comment: @Nmath A larger block size yields higher throughput.It took overnight perhaps because the card is very slow but I don't think it's related to that large block size.See [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*F649V83i72apqsDAv93aKg.png).And AFAIK the most common block size is 4096 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

**One possible answer is that something is seriously wrong with the SD card.**

I've recently battled with slowness & random erros on 4 SD cards, and discovered that they were all fakes. I now always test new cards before using them. This answer may not be the solution in this particular case, but it may help someone, and I don't (yet) have the reputation to Comment.

**Fake cards can be slow, they can also over-state their size** (failing when you reach the real size limit).

A simple SD card test (covering speed & size) is provided by the [H2testw](https://www.heise.de/download/product/h2testw-50539) application. From that page:

> The software finds out whether a storage medium actually offers as
> much storage space as specified by the manufacturer. The information
> is not always correct due to errors or fraud, so a USB stick check is
> advisable.

It's for Windows, but also:

> If you use the operating systems macOS, Ubuntu, Linux Mint or Debian,
> you can use the command line program F3 as an alternative to H2Testw,
> which is available as free freeware.

(Translation by [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/))

The site is in German, and within the application you can toggle between German & English.

**H2testw is recognised as the Gold Standard in detecting fakes.**

**BEWARE**: H2testw will write random data to the SD card, so effectively **erasing** it.

I suggest testing "all available space", and then being patient (it took about an hour to test a 32GB card).

Note: H2testw replaces [H2Test](https://www.heise.de/download/product/h2test-19574):

> The newer H2testw is more convenient and especially recommended for
> testing USB sticks.

H2testw tests a formatted SD card, and if the partitions have been deleted then they need to be replaced. A very quick list of instructions which can often get back from a corrupted card to a formated card (using Windows):

DISKPART (right click an Run As Administrator)

- list disk
- select disk <number of the SD card, **don't get this wrong!!!**>
- list disk (to be sure you selected the right disk)
- clean
- create partition primary
- active
- exit
  Then format as normal.

BTW: I would also recommend Etcher for writing SD cards - it does a verify so can indicate a problem.